# size of legend is too big and cex is not useful

Tags: r, plot, legend

I am plotting with r, but the legend is too big. when I reduce the cex, the text shrinks but the legend box still has huge empty spaces. the legend code is:

```
legend('topleft',adj = c(0, 0.6), pch=c(4,1), c("non smokers", "smokers"), cex=.75,horiz = TRUE,pt.cex = 1)
```

how can I fix this?thx

[image]

Comment: @d.b, it is 800x800, but doesn't work! no matter what size I select, still is too big.

Comment: @Cina  Please help us by giving us a [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Use `dput` to provide the data for the plot and the code that you used to create the plot - not just the legend.

Comment: You can probably get some help by including `bty="n" ` in your legend statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First specify the plot size using `windows` or `pdf` or `png` and it will be fine. Here's an example using `png`

```
graphics.off()
png(filename = "test.png", width = 7, height = 7, units = "in", res = 75)
plot(1:10, 1:10)
legend('topleft', pch=c(4,1), c("non smokers", "smokers"), horiz = TRUE)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: it works in this way. but, I am plotting in rstudio, using it for viewing the plot. In this way, the legend size is still big. Can I fix it by giving any parameter to the legend?